# React keys in dynamic lists

Tags: reactjs

This is from the Facebook documentation:

> When a list is rerendered, React takes each element in the new version
>   and looks for one with a matching key in the previous list. When a key
>   is added to the set, a component is created; when a key is removed, a
>   component is destroyed. Keys tell React about the identity of each
>   component, so that it can maintain the state across rerenders. If you
>   change the key of a component, it will be completely destroyed and
>   recreated with a new state.
>
> It's strongly recommended that you assign proper keys whenever you
>   build dynamic lists. If you don't have an appropriate key handy, you
>   may want to consider restructuring your data so that you do.
>
> If you don't specify any key, React will warn you and fall back to
>   using the array index as a key – which is not the correct choice if
>   you ever reorder elements in the list or add/remove items anywhere but
>   the bottom of the list. Explicitly passing key={i} silences the
>   warning but has the same problem so isn't recommended in most cases.
>
> Component keys don't need to be globally unique, only unique relative
>   to the immediate siblings.

I don't get it. If we don't supply keys in a list like this:

```
return (
        <li>
          <a href="#" onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</a>
        </li>
      );
```

What is the problem? If the list had 3 elements and the keys were `[0,1,2]` and we removed `1`, what would happen?

Comment: you can find the answer [here](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/react-dot-js-and-dynamic-children-why-the-keys-are-important/)

Answer (score 0):

Each list needs a key for only React to use; like this `<li key={item.uniqueId}>` where the `uniqueId` of the `item` is unique in the group of items. So when you modify this list React knows how to deal with the modification. This key is different from the index/positioning of a single item in a list.

When you create a list using a map like so you'll do something like this:

```
return (
    <ul>
       {this.props.items.map(item => <ItemComponent key={item.id} {...item} />)}
    </ul>
)
```

In the documentation you posted above you *could* use the item's index (ie, `(index, i) => <ItemComponent key={i}`) but it's not recommended.

In the `ItemComponent` list component:

```
return (
  <li>
    {/* your code here */}
  </li>
)
```

Or using your example you could do it like this:

```
return (
  <li key={this.props.uniqueId}>
    <a href="#" onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</a>
  </li>
);
```

Any time you move, delete or add items to this list React will know how to render it.